# Why my form open not working in laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Hi all I have problame with my form I am writing html form but its error
and this is my route code

```
Route::get('course','CourseController@index');
```

and this is my CourseController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CourseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('course.create');
    }
```

and this is my view  course/create.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'course.store')) !!}

        <input type="text"><br>
        <input type="password"><br>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 FatalErrorException in 818f720d4e075893d8198d2b0ff02e25 line 9: Class 'Form' not found
```

Help me please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Laravel 5.* the `Form` & `Html` have been deprecated. Check out [uprade guide](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.0) (search `Form & HTML Helpers`).

**1. Install `laravelcollective/html`**

> composer require laravelcollective/html

**2. Add the `Form` and `HTML` facades and service provider.**

Edit `config/app.php` and add this line to the 'providers' array:

```
'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

Next, add these lines to the 'aliases' array:

```
'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
```